# WCF - quick response with status then continue doing longer process

Tags: wcf

I spent few days search on this case.  I checked out all wcf asynchronous implementaions. 
I wasn't able to find what I was looking for.

Below is scenario.

1. WCF is running to accept xml
2. WCF needs to response to user for success receiving xml and release
   the request immediately
3. WCF then needs to do processing to save xml to database and parsing xml to
   convert something else.

I don't want to use separate service to process above.  I want to use one service to handle all 3 cases above.

I checked out asynchronous way of coding in WCF, but this doesn't release the request right away.  What is the best practice for this?  Is there any sample code I can use?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How would WCF know which parts you want completed before returning a response? I think you need to split this up yourself and queue the latter part of your processing for asynchronous processing, e.g. via a thread, thread pool, or other internal async call.

Comment: What you suggested is something I went over.  I just want to see if there is any other better solution to do it.  thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would be better suited to using a different technology. Maybe look at Windows Workflow Foundation.

You can host WCF Workflow Services the same way as you host a standard WCF service, the main difference is that you can create specific workflows that can continue after acknowledging receipt of the original message.

You do this by persisting the message and returning to the user. WF allows you to create actions that continue after sending response back to the caller.

Visual studio provides you with a design surface that allows you to drag and drop components  to create custom workflows. Additionally you can also make calls to other services if required.

With .net 4.5 you can now use C#, in previous versions of WF you had to use VB.net.

You can read about it on the MSDN site here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/jj684582.aspx

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you your answer.  i checked out wf initially then decided not to go due to debugging issues.  May be I need to take a look at this one more time in depth.